# Return object after DispatchGroup with RxSwift

Tags: iphone, swift, grand-central-dispatch, rx-swift, dispatch-queue

I am using DispatchGroup to download data from 3 different APIs, once this is done I want to return the new created consolidated object from my function. Now Although DispatchGroup is working fine and I am getting data but I am not able to return it to calling function. Following is my function:

```
func getHowToInfo(materialNo: String) -> Observable<HowToInfo> {
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        _ = self.getMaterialInfo(materialNo: materialNo).subscribe(onNext:{ material in

            let howto = HowToInfo(videos: [], documents: [], applications: [])

            if (material.documentTargetId?.count)! > 0 {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                _ = self.materialRepo?.API1(targetIDs: material.documentTargetId!).subscribe(onNext:{documents in
                    howto.documents = documents
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }, onError: { (error) in
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }
            if (material.applicationDescription?.count)! > 0 {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                _ = self.materialRepo?.API2(materialNo: materialNo).subscribe(onNext:{applications in
                    howto.applications = applications
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }, onError: { (error) in
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }
            if ((material.videoApplicationTargetId?.count) != nil && (material.videoApplicationTargetId?.count)! > 0) {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                _ = self.materialRepo?.API3(targetIDs: material.videoApplicationTargetId!).subscribe(onNext:{videos in
                    howto.videos = videos
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }, onError: { (error) in
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }else if ((material.videoSupportTargetId?.count) != nil && (material.videoSupportTargetId?.count)! > 0) {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                _ = self.materialRepo?.API4(targetIDs: material.videoSupportTargetId!).subscribe(onNext:{videos in
                    howto.videos = videos
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }, onError: { (error) in
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                print("All functions complete ")
                observer.onNext(howto)
                observer.onCompleted()
            })
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

calling function:

```
func loadHowToUseList(materialNo: String){
    self.serviceMaterial.getHowToInfo(materialNo: materialNo).subscribe({
        howToUse in
        print(howToUse)
    }).disposed(by: DisposeBag())
}
```

I am not able to get my object in subscribe method above, it never runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
dispatchGroup.wait()
```

After your lines

```
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            print("All functions complete ")
            observer.onNext(howto)
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
```

And also, why don't just use Rx operators itself?

Every one of this could be an `observer.onNext`, then you try to observe on three events of this observable,  and there is no need for `onCompleted`

Comment: Actually all these calls are random, I don't know which one will complete first, I want to return the object once all 3 calls are completed

Comment: I also added dispatchGroup.wait() after but now notify block is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve desired behaviour using combineLatest and skipWhile operators. Roughly implementation would be like this:

```
    let api1 = Observable.of(["documents"])    //Replace with observable to download docs
    let api2 = Observable.of(["applications"]) //Replace with observable to download apps
    let api3 = Observable.of(["videos"])       //Replace with observable to download videos

    Observable.combineLatest(api1, api2, api3){(docs, apps, videos) in
        return (docs, apps, videos)
    }.skipWhile{ (docs, apps, videos) in
        return docs.count == 0 && apps.count == 0 && videos.count == 0
    }.subscribe(onNext:{(docs, apps, videos) in

    })
    .disposed(by:disposeBag)
```